# how can i use the PHP method $_GET[] with the same variable name in different php files

Tags: php, forms

In index.php, I have created a form and in the action attribute of the form tag I have specified "page2.php".

page2.php is also a form, (which continues on from index.php) and in the action attribute of the form tage I have specified "page3.php". I can retrieve what the user entered into the "location" text box, in the form on index.php and display it in page2.php through the method 
`<?php echo $_GET["location"]; ?>`

but, I now also want to display the user location in page3.php, but when I use the above method it does not work. It give me the error: "Undefined index: location". I take it is because page3.php can not access the fields from index.php, but how do I get this to work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Use a Session!](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Comment: come on people, sessions? Yeah, it's an option but if this guy is asking this question like this it does not help in the least to simply say USE SESSIONS and give not even a short example. A link is useful to follow a brief example, but just a link is lazy and might just confuse new programmers without some kind of starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to store the value of $_GET["location"]; in a hidden field on page2.php within the form that gets submitted to page3.php.

Update Example

page2.php

```
<form action="page3.php">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php print $_GET['location']; ?>" name="location_from_page2" />
```

page3.php

```
$location = $_GET["location_from_page2"];
```

What you're doing here is printing out the contents of location into the value of a hidden field and then you're reading this hidden field in page3.php

This is one way to do it but you might want to consider looking into the php sessions.

Comment: I saw something about 'hidden' in another post but can't seem to find it. Are you able to give my an example please?

Comment: No problem, you should go ahead and accept an answer to your question. And I don't necessarily mean my answer, just the best fitting one. You can click the little check mark in order to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Try using session variables

```
$_SESSION['location'] = $_GET['location'];
```

Comment: Once you store your values on the session you will be able to access them from other pages.  
The values you have in $_GET or $_POST are those you received from a `<form>` element, and only exist in the page that received them (the one after the form submit).  If you use hidden fields you would be putting them in the second form again and you will receive them again when the user submits the form, but if you validated those values before you will have to revalidate them (as the user can tamper with the hidden fields and change them).

Comment: Also, if you're dealing with several values I'd recommend to use `<form method="post">` (instead of `get`) and them get the values from $_POST.
Post can handle larger data and the values will not be visible in the URL.

Comment: thanks Brett and Sebastian. I stored the value in a hidden field and it works now. But I am considering using sessions like you mentioned. I haven't used it before and I am new to php. But would i create the session in index.php or page2.php? And why is it better than using the hidden value approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can use hidden fields to achieve this.

page2.php:

```
<form id="myform" action="/page3.php" method="get">
    <fieldset>
        <label>x</label> <input type="text" name="something" value=""><br><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="location" value="<?php echo $_GET['location']; ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the values in your form on the 2nd page.

Like: `<input type="hidden" name="location" value="<?= $_GET["location"]; ?>">`

or append the variable to your action in the form.

Otherwise you could just use Sessions - which would probably be easiest.